# NSMutableArray Thread Concurrency with GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I have an NSMutableArray in a "sharedStore"-pattern singleton.

Publicly, it's accessible only through methods that cast it as an NSArray. Within the class, it's

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *myItems;
```

This array never gets manipulated outsdie the singleton but ViewControllers send the singleton messages to manipulate this controller. Some of these messages empty the array, some re-populate it, etc.

Having ended up in a situation where the array was empty in one method call and not yet empty in the next, I've started implementing some concurrency behaviour.

*Here's what I'm doing so far:*

In the .m file of the singleton, I have a

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t arrayAccessQueue;
```

In my singleton's initializer it gets created as a serial queue. And then, every method that has anything to do with mutating this array does so from within a `dispatch_sync` call, for example:

```
dispatch_sync(self.arrayAccessQueue, ^{
    [_myItems removeAllObjects];
});
```

This has made things better and has made my app behave more smoothly. However, I have no way of quantifying that beyond it having fixed that one odd behaviour described above. I also kind of feel like I'm in the dark as to any problems that may be lurking beneath the surface.

This pattern makes sense to me, but should I be using something else, like `@synchronize` or `NSLock` or `NSOperationQueue`? Will this come back to bite me?

Comment: BTW - did you properly implement an explicit setter method for your `myItems` property? If not, you will have problems due to the `copy` attribute on the mutable property.

Comment: Hmm. I did not know that. You mean `_myItems = [myItems copy]`? I thought the compiler did that automatically now and that it didn't need to be done explicitly anymore? Am I wrong?

Comment: The problem is that `[myItems copy]` returns an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`, even when called on a mutable array. You need to override the `setMyItems:` method and call `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Damn, good point. It hadn’t yet caused any problems because I was referring to it as `_myItems` in my code. (Yes, bad form...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dispatch_sync` is fine as long as you wrap all array reads and writes and you ensure it is a serial queue.

But you could improve things by allowing concurrent reads. To do this, use `dispatch_sync` around all array reads and use `dispatch_barrier_sync` around all array writes. And setup the queue to be concurrent.

Do this ensures only a single write can happen at a time, reads will be block until the write is done, and a write will wait until all current reads are done.

Comment: Thanks. I would also use the barrier for removing objects, correct?

Comment: Yes since removing is considered a "write". Anything that changes the contents of the array is a "write" and need to use the barrier sync.

Comment: Technically, `NSMutableArray` is not thread safe for readonly operations, either.  Unless the documentation explicitly states otherwise, you cannot assume thread safety.   (I'm pretty sure it is actually implemented to be thread safe during read operations, though.)   This probably needs to be clarified in the documentation.

Comment: @bbum I can't imagine any implementation of `NSMutableArray/NSArray` that would render concurrent reads as unsafe.

Comment: @rmaddy, I suppose if the getter somehow ‘preps’ the array, e.g. by resorting it or decorating its contents, that could be one such implementation. But that's kind of constructed.

Comment: @rmaddy I can and have seen such implementations, but they are rare.  Mutable collections often transition from lots-of-reads-and-writes to almost-exclusively-readonly.  When that transition is detected or hinted, the array may internally optimize itself for retrieval speed vs. insertion speed.  I don't think that is in play here, but -- as with all things threading -- assume thread unsafe until claimed (and tested) otherwise!

Comment: @rmaddy simply think of an implementation that keeps a list of tiles to make writing faster (i. e. inserting in the middle) and that decides to reorganize the tiles on read accesses, i. e. when detecting that the array is read incrementally very often or when a fast enumeration comes in.

Comment: … and likely this is the reason, why there is no documented (= reliable) behavior.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad The implementation at https://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSArray is simple enough and certainly appears to be thread-safe for reading.

Comment: The actual implementation somewhere seems to be thread-safe. What do you want to say with this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a GCD queue concurrent and providing sort of accessor to your array you can synchronize reading and writing by using dispatch_sync while reading and dispatch_barrier_async while writing.

```
- (id)methodToRead {
  id __block obj = nil;
  dispatch_sync(syncQueue, ^{
     obj = <#read_Something#>;
  });
  return obj;
}

- (void) methodsForWriting:(id)obj {
   dispatch_barrier_async(syncQueue, ^{
    // write passing obj to something
  });
}
```

This will guarantee that during writing everything is locked from reading.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dispatch_barrier_sync` for writing?

Comment: Depends, _async means that the method returns before the block is executed. But block execution sequence should be guaranteed by the sync queue itself. Of course it sounds more appropriate .

Answer (score 0):

Using GCD is the right choice. The only "gotcha" is that you need to do ALL operations on that queue: add, remove, insert, etc.

I will also mention you need to ensure that you do not use a concurrent queue. You should be using a serial queue, which is the default anyways.